# C++ Bool tests using Variable Arguments "..."

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

Is it possible to do a `Boolean` test on multiple objects when passing them using the Variable Argument List `"..."`?

Example function:

```
    bool check_collision( SPRITE sprite, PLATFORM platform ...){
         //do check
         return true;
    }
```

Calling like:

```
    if(check_collision(sprite,platform,platform2,platform3,platform4,platform5)){
          //manipulate sprite
    }
```

instead of like:

```
    if((check_collision(sprite,platform)
        && (check_collision(sprite,platform2)
        && (check_collision(sprite,platform3)
        && (check_collision(sprite,platform4)
        && (check_collision(sprite,platform5)){
        //manipulate sprite
    }
```

or:

```
    if((check_collision(sprite,platform)
        || (check_collision(sprite,platform2)
        || (check_collision(sprite,platform3)
        || (check_collision(sprite,platform4)
        || (check_collision(sprite,platform5)){
        //manipulate sprite
    }
```

If testing them all using the `"..."`, would you have to iterate through each platform/compare the sprite with each platform? 
Would they all have to return `true` for the boolean test to be true or only one?
I'm guessing you would have to send a 3rd `Argument` so the function knows whether the bool would be an `OR` or and `AND`? (so if OR, only one has to be true, if AND, all have to be true?)

I have tested it within the program I'm currently working on, but I haven't implemented
any iteration so I'm pretty sure its only checking the first `platform`.

Comment: varargs are just a way to accept an unspecified amount of arguments, without explicitly declaring them as part of the function signature. Everything else (ie. everything you asked) is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdarg.h>
double checkAll(int count, SPRITE sprite, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int j;
    boolean result = false;
    va_start(ap, sprite); //Requires the last fixed parameter (to get the address)
    for(j=0; j<count; ++j){
        result = result || checkCollision(sprite, va_arg(ap, PLATFORM)); 
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ah this is cool. Very nice code. Thanks for taking the time to write it. Going to try it now :D